# Не удается вставить svg через background

Tags: css3, html5

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgOCAyNCI+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtIDAuMzA3NTUwMzIsMTcuMTI5Njc0IDQuNTc5OTk5OTgsLTQuNTkgLTQuNTc5OTk5OTgsLTQuNTg5OTk5IDEuNDA5OTk5OTgsLTEuNDEwMDAwMyA2LDUuOTk5OTk5MyAtNiw2IHoiIGZpbGw9IiNmZmZmZmYiLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background-position: right;
height: 24px;
width: 100px;
```

Не понимаю, в чем дело? Необходимо расположить иконку по правому краю и растянуть во всю высоту блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

установите свойство
display: block;
z-index: 99;

Comment: Не работает, не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: измени просто на background: url();

Comment: xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" что необходимо было добавить при конверктации